# How can I parse jQuery variable that has the value of attr("title") back to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I have got a variable called name here

```
Name = $(this).attr("title");
```

I need to parse this back to HTML, i.e.

```
Nudging <script>document.write (Name);</script>
```

But its not working, I think its something to do with scopes

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "parse back to HTML". There is probably a better way than using `document.write`. Can you make an example?

Comment: The `Name` var contains title not element.

Comment: If you check here... 

http://forum.castoff.net/menu.php

the Dim button has a title of 'Me' I just want it to display it as a name in the popup box after Nudging...

Comment: You appear to have updated your code at the link shown to use Glauber's suggestion and it seems to be doing exactly what you want. Don't forget to make @Glauber's answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Nudging <script>document.write (Name);</script>
```

Use something like:

```
Nudging <span id="someId"></span>
```

And this line of jQuery:

```
$("#someId").html(Name);
```

Check what exactly `this` is supposed to select in your expression. In the code at the URL  you give, you could select like this:

```
Name = $(".alertdim").attr("title");
```

See the jQuery selectors reference here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Fantastic... I have put the code in that you said and its works perfectly... all i need now is another but that lets me parse through a userid in a hidden <input>

Comment: You should be able to do a similar thing, although using `$("selector_for_input").val();` rather than the `.attr("title");` part.

Comment: OK cool but how do i insert the variable in to the <input type=hidden value=''> ?

Comment: `$("input").attr("value",someValue);` But here, the selector "input" I'm using selects all `<input>` elements in your document, so this is unlikely to be specific enough. You will probably want to use a selector that uniquely selects this `input` element, for instance by adding in `id` attribute.

Comment: Hmmm i've put that code in... doesnt' seem to be working for me :-(